# Datatable primeng with lazyload and virtualscroll

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, primeng

I have a primeng datatable with lazyload and virtual scroll, but when i scroll i see an entire refresh of my table, this is the video:
[Video example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_she6Q8vsHrbDgwNElaRng5azA)
and not only new elements loading like the example in [Primeng site](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/scroll)

This is my table

```
<p-dataTable [value]="products" scrollable="true" virtualScroll="virtualScroll" scrollHeight="200px" [rows]="10" [style]="{'margin-top':'30px'}"
        [lazy]="true" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" (onLazyLoad)="loadProductsLazy($event)">
        <p-header>Virtual Scrolling - {{totalRecords}} Rows</p-header>
        <p-column field="code" header="Codice" [sortable]="true" ></p-column>
        <p-column field="transportType" header="transportType"[sortable]="true" ></p-column> 
    </p-dataTable>
```

Is it a problem with lazyload or something else?

Comment: please remove the `angularjs` tag as this is an `angular2` question

Comment: Did you figure out? Please post the video, it's no longer available. I have few issues with `virtualScroll` feature even on the latest 4.0.1

Comment: no, I just remove virtual scroll, probably I do some errors implementing it

Comment: I have a similar problem, I can see the refresh (everything goes blank for a while), also my filters wont work anymore

Comment: This has all to do with what your filling products with, after loadProductsLazy(). Look at what the server is returning, what your object is before angular updates UI.